# opencv, findContour error (windows breakpoint), c++, ms Visual studio 2010, win7, 64bit

Tags: opencv

I've asked this question on opencv.org, without any luck, so no I hope that someone here can help me.

I am developing a face/eye tracking software. To measure some values from the eyes (blinks for example). But when I want to use the method

```
cv::findContour()
```

The program crashes with a : "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in eyeTracking.exe....."
No error message from opencv in the console.

```
m = ~currentWebCamFrame(trackP.EyePosition(false));
cv::cvtColor(m,n, CV_RGB2GRAY);
cv::threshold(n, m, threshold-value, 255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cv::erode(m, n, cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1,-1),n_erode_dilate);
cv::dilate(n, m, cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1,-1),n_erode_dilate);

test = m.clone();

if((!test.empty()) && (test.type() == CV_8UC1)){
std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours( test, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
};
```

I've searched the internet and found a couple of similar posts like this, without any solution.

My post @ opencv.org :
http://answers.opencv.org/question/12887/opencvfindcontour-crashes-v244-ms-visual-studio/
Where the image is visible right before the findContour is called.

Ive tried to solve this now for a couple of days, without any luck. So I really hope that someone here can help me fix this problem.

**edit:**
When clicking on continue on the breakpoint window, this message comes up:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x770540f2 in eyeTracking.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap is damaged.
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly, findContours works with white blobs. Try it with its inverted image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. unfortunately it didnt work :(

Comment: Can you give it a try by NOT making a clone? Just allocate the correct size and channel for 'test' variable and see if it works. Or otherwise you might possibly need to check the DLL's you have used. mixing debug with release dll's etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might possibly need to check the DLL's you have used. Mixing debug with release dll's can cause the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I linked to wrong opencv libraries. I used some of the release libraries during debug. Changing to debug libraries made everything work.

Comment: Was my comment the answer? :)

Comment: Yes! Sorry, forgot to give you the cred for it!. Thank you Wajih! if you post an answer, I'll mark it as answer. doooh it :D