# Why do I receive breakpoints by findContours?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been trying to set up a program that uses HSV to detect a specific colour and place a rectangle around the biggest area found of said colour. I am having problems when i get to the vectors and the "findContours" function, which stops the program with an error stating "xxx.exe has triggered a break point".

This only happens when I insert the line

```
findContours(dilatedBlue,contours,hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

I'm a rookie when it comes to OpenCV and C++ but I'm hoping someone will be able to help. I'm using windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV 2.4.8.

My full code is what follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

// Declare Local Variables
int Quit = 0;
Mat imageDiff;
Mat HSVMatrix[3];
Mat erodedBlue;
Mat dilatedBlue;


//Start of search/shoot routine
while( Quit != 'q' )    // For as long as User wishes to continue...
{

    Mat image;
    cap >> image; // get a new frame from camera
    imshow("Original", image);
    //GaussianBlur(image, image, Size(3,3), 1.5, 1.5);            // Setting up a Gaussian blur using 5x5 grid
    cvtColor(image, imageDiff, CV_BGR2HSV);
    split(imageDiff,HSVMatrix);

    //Setting up saturation values for colour blue
    threshold(HSVMatrix[0],HSVMatrix[0],130,255,THRESH_TOZERO_INV);    // High value of colour - Dynamic changing of variable to select mode 130
    threshold(HSVMatrix[0],HSVMatrix[0],75,255,THRESH_BINARY);        // Low  value of colour 75
    threshold(HSVMatrix[1],HSVMatrix[1],255,255,THRESH_TOZERO_INV);    // High saturation value - Modify for varying levels of light
    threshold(HSVMatrix[1],HSVMatrix[1],100,255,THRESH_BINARY);        // Low saturation value

    HSVMatrix[2]=HSVMatrix[1]&HSVMatrix[0];
    imshow("HSVblue", HSVMatrix[2]);            // Displays binarised image
    erode(HSVMatrix[2], HSVMatrix[2], Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
    erode(HSVMatrix[2], erodedBlue, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
    imshow("Eroded-Blue", erodedBlue);
    dilate(erodedBlue, dilatedBlue, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);
    imshow("Dilated-Blue", dilatedBlue);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;        // Temporary variables used to hold contour information
    vector<Point> approx;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
    findContours(dilatedBlue,contours,hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true) * 0.02, true);               // Calculation of contours and their approximate size and sides
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            if ((approx.size() == 4) && (fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 100))                                     // The properties that have to be fulfilled in order for the object to be recognized by the computer
            {
                Rect outline;                                                                                 // If the properties have been fulfilled and the object has been recognized, display an outline around the object
                outline = boundingRect(approx);
                rectangle(image,Rect(outline),Scalar(0, 255, 255),5,8,0);                                       // The properties of the outline: the colour[bgr] and thickness
            }
        }
        imshow("Target", image);
    }

    Quit = cvWaitKey(1);                   // The program waits for the key "q" to be pressed to exit
}
cap.release();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: First off, do you know what a breakpoint is?

Comment: from what i was taught a breakpoint is used to break the execution of a program when a value in the memory changes. I'm hoping that's correct

Comment: Thats not a comprehensive list.  A break point is a point at which execution of the program "Breaks" into the debugger.  It suspends execution.  Open up your breakpoint window and see what you have listed there.  If you dont have any breakpoints set then the only other way to get one is to call a function which triggers one, such as __debugbreak(), or firing the appropriate interupt.

Comment: I didn't have any breakpoints set, that's why I was wondering what was causing the program to suspend itself out of nowhere. The only function that seems to cause that breakpoint is the line I posted regarding the findContours. When that is out of the way the program doesn't trigger any breakpoints.

Comment: Do you have the source code for that function?  Most likely you are tripping a programmer imposed assertion where they thought calling __debugbreak without any information would be helpfull.. Also you should try doing some research, google search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390200/opencv-findcontour-error-windows-breakpoint-c-ms-visual-studio-2010-win7

Comment: I read the article you linked and it seems to be the same problem I'm encountering, although i didn't quite understand the solution to it. I have done some research but I'm not quite sure what exactly is the problem with the code itself.

Comment: The solution linked is not a code problem.  It very clearly states that it is a problem with mixing release dll's and debug dll's.  Or more specific to the asker, mixing linking debug with release libs,  For example passing in a growable array that was created on one heap like the debug and trying to grow or release it on another like release.. Make sure you are linking and or importing from the proper build.

Comment: As I said, I am a rookie when it come to C++ and OpenCV, I know about the Release and Debug libraries but I wouldn't know where to start to make sure i am linking and/or importing from the proper build. But thanks anyways

Comment: Then I suggest you do your homework.  BTW, its a lot easier to find answers you'll find when you actually google the problem first.  Instead of reposting duplicates.  When everyone is too lazy to research, and just posts questions, then the guy who does try to google it finds 300 pages of the same question which takes him all week to sort through.  I mention this because, I already gave you a link to the same question with some people who have already solved it.  You might want to consider asking them, in that thread..