# OpenCV - FindContours - Projekt.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, dll

I use VS2013 with opencv 3.1. 
I have almost the same code like here: [opencv, findContour error (windows breakpoint), c++, ms Visual studio 2010, win7, 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390200/opencv-findcontour-error-windows-breakpoint-c-ms-visual-studio-2010-win7/16423763#16423763?newreg=e45c11715be9426686b1b97c273716ae)

I want to find contours in my image and I already transformed the image into a binary and thresholded the picture so I can use "findcontours".
I think I'm getting the same error like the one in the link but I don't understand the answer.

I installed opencv like in the documentation and added the path and opencv-dir correct. In my project I added the libs in properties-linker-general and in properties-linker-input.
In the documentation of version 2.4.1 they added several libs but in 3.1 i just found the two libs opencv_world310.lib and opencv_world310d.lib.

I added them both in properties-linker-input. Is this correct.
I don't know what it means to "mix" debug and release DLLs also I tried to google the difference.

I hope someone can help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you are building an app in "Debug" mode, and are linking it to libraries that are built using the "Release" configuration. You can check which configuration is selected by looking at VS toolbar, there is a drop-down selection for build configuration (the default is "Debug").

Here is what you need to do to fix the issue. Link to `opencv_world310d.lib` in "Debug" mode and link to `opencv_world310.lib` in "Release" mode. To do this, open project properties, select "Debug" from "Configuration" drop-down control and add `opencv_world310d.lib` to Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies. Apply these changes, switch to "Release" in "Configuration" and add `opencv_world310.lib` as additional dependency.

Comment: On top of not mixing debug and release it is important to use the correct libs / dlls. For Visual Studio 2013 make sure you use the binaries in the vc12 folder of the binary download. Yes vc12 = Visual Studio 2013. vc11 = Visual Studio 2012.